# Do I need to validate the UserInfo of AuthenticationResult like we need for the token?

Tags: asp.net, jwt, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adal

So I use the `ADAL` library to implement Azure Directory Single Sign On to my app.
[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)

I add the `{ "scope", "openid"}` to the request url so the `id_token` is returned. I then retrieve the user's unique id to look up in the database.

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(MicrosoftAuthBaseURL);

ClientCredential clcred = new ClientCredential(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppSecret);
AuthenticationResult acResult = ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(RedirectURI), clcred).Result;

SignInUser(acResult.UserInfo.UniqueId);
```

I am aware that it is a good practice to validate the access token or the id token, but in my case neither of these token is used directly. I just retrieve/use the `UniqueId` field. So my question is, do I still need to do any validation here, what should I validate and is there any built in validation method I can leverage in the library? I prefer not to do in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I would say validation is not mandatory because you receive the token in direct response from Azure AD.
If someone can intercept and replace the token, then they can replace the signing keys your application retrieves as well.
Which would mean they would be able to forge any token they want.